# My String Is Not Converting to a Float and I have No Idea Why

Tags: python

I'm importing some text files and trying to plot some data, however, I keep getting the error message:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Here's the portion of my code that's giving me trouble. Do you see any issues with this? 
Thank you!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab 

fluxdensity = []
days= []
with open('knowniaxflux.csv') as f:
     for row in f.readlines():  
        row.strip('\n')
        if not row.startswith("#"):
            spaces = row.split(',')
            fluxdensity.append(float(spaces[0]))
            days.append(float(spaces[1]))
```

Comment: `float("1.21 Gigawatts")` -> ValueError. You've got something in a string that can't parse as a float (actually looks like an empty string, ie `float('')` -> ValueError)

Comment: Could you post some of the data in 'knowniaxflux.csv'?

Comment: Also, this message doesn't actually seem to affect the end result I'm looking for, it's just weird.

Comment: 77,96,#8.4 /
-59,57.8,#8.4 /
-23,24,#8.4 /
-15,7,#4.1 /

Comment: Try using `strip()` after `split()` in `spaces`

Comment: print spaces[0], you will know why it is not able to convert.

Comment: Why don't you put the conversions in `try` blocks, catch the `ValueError`, and `print` the offending string?

Comment: Considering that there's no value specified in the error message, I'm guessing that you ended up passing in whitespace to `float`. Are there rows without at least two columns?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just not getting the input you expect. You should use `print` statements to see what you're actually trying to convert (While debugging, of course. Remove them later).

In addition, unless you know exactly how your input looks like, you probably need a more solid parser anyways. For example `#`'s might not be the first character in the file. You might want to specify an encoding to the file (unless you're always using ASCII/UTF-8 (PY2/PY3) anyways.). You might also want to strip spaces if you expect any.

If all else fails, in my experience your file is written in the wrong encoding. Make sure your file is written using one of the encodings mentioned above, and preferably convert you binary input to Unicode format (especially if you're using PY3. That would be the `str` object). Read the Python Unicode HOWTO, it should make it all clear.